# How do I mock a domain in Grails but get it by its Parent?

Tags: grails, groovy, mocking, subclass

I am using the spring security core plugin within my grails application and by default it creates me a User class.  I can mock this using the @Mock([User]) annotation on my test class.

In my application I have several types of User so I created subtypes which works great in the application itself.

```
Subtype1 extends User
Subtype2 extends User
```

This is handled in grails perfectly fine and the database reflects this too.  In my code however, I do have methods which can be called by general Users so I use the User.get(id) since the id is the same for both Subtype and Parent.

If I mock User and Subtype and then create a Subtype object as follows

```
@TestFor(MyController)
@Mock([Subtype1,User])
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {
  def test_methodName() {
    setup:
    Subtype1 sub = new Subtype1(username:"blah",password:"blah",.....).save()
    when:
    controller.methodName(sub.id)
    then:
    //Some tests here
}
```

Then the following code is annotated to show the outcomes

```
class MyController() {
    methodName(long id) {
        User user = User.get(id)  //This returns null
        Subtype1 sub = Subtype1.get(id)  //This works
    }
}
```

In the application when not being tested both work however when I mock them it fails and doesn't let me get parents when created as a child.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this just isn't possible within a Unit test, whether intentional or not.

Writing the test as an integration test works fine.